# OpenLiberty server.xml boolean variable data-types

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty, microprofile

OpenLiberty does not seem to support variable substitution of boolean data-types.  I have a MicroProfile JWT configuration element (ignoreApplicationAuthMethod) that I would like to tokenize.  Are there best practices for externalizing boolean parameters needed in server.xml?  To work around this I have pulled the entire mpJwt configuration element up into our parent environment specific xml, but this in not ideal as not every server requires this mpJwt configuration.

What I would like to do:

```
`<mpJwt audiences="myAud" id="${jwtBuilderName}" ignoreApplicationAuthMethod="${enforceJwt}" issuer="http://openliberty.io" keyName="secretKey" mapToUserRegistry="false"/>`
```

Comment: how/where are you specifying `enforceJwt`?

Comment: also, have you considered breaking this JWT configuration out into its own XML file (such as jwtConfig.xml) and then every server that needs JWT can `<include>` it?

Comment: My variable is specified as `<variable name="enforceJwt" value="true"/>`.  I think your suggestion of breaking out the jwt config into its own XML is the way to go. Thanks

Comment: Ha, actually had a typo, sorry.  I was totally wrong, the variable substitution works.  Helps when you dont misspell `variable`.  Thanks though.

Comment: Also you should be aware that we don't support variable substitution for the id="${jwtBuilderName}" on any element.